# How does IPC::System::Simple capturex work?

Tags: perl

The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple#runx(),-systemx()-and-capturex()) of `capurex`, states that the function *never invokes the shell*.

**My assumption:**
Since no shell is invoked, characters like `*` or `;` will not get interpreted and therefore can't do harm.
This is why calls to external programs are not (or less) susceptible to accidentally malformed input or intended injection attacks as shown in the example below (sorry for the German output messages):

```
use v5.26;
use IPC::System::Simple 'capturex';

# (very) vulnerable to shell injection
say `ls @ARGV`;

# just a visual line
say '----------';

# no shell injection "possible" (?)
say capturex('ls', @ARGV);
```

The output:

```
user@host:-$ perl shell-injection.pl -1 \*.pl \; hostname
shell-injection.pl
host

----------
ls: Zugriff auf '*.pl' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden 
ls: Zugriff auf ';' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden 
ls: Zugriff auf 'hostname' nicht möglich: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden 
"ls" unexpectedly returned exit value 2 at shell-injection.pl line 11. 
user@host:-$
```

My Questions:

1. What terminologies can be used to describe, how the code is executed with `capturex`? What are examples / techniques / terms used in other languages or environments? (e.g. `system call`?)
2. Is it actually advisable to use this technique without input checking (I assume not) and if not, for what reason (attack vector)?

Comment: My conclusion from the answers below is something along those lines: 1) "capturex" uses "execvp" which is a "system call" to the underlying operating system. 2) Since no shell is used, shell-injection is not possible, but this is not a security feature in itself and should thus not be relied on. Can you guys help me by up-voting, which answer should be accepted? :-) thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to get informed about how `capturex` operates is by looking at [its source](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-System-Simple/source/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm#L363).

The sub implements its own piped open in "list-form", to work around the (ancient!) v5.6.x limitations. It does so by `fork`-ing a process using *piped open* and then "manually" `exec`-ing the command in the child, where it can use the list-form. Then the output is read in the parent. Follow the word "pipe" in the [open](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) page, and then the link to [perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html).

So there can be no shell involved since [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) in the LIST form uses `execvp(3)` system call to directly run the command. (What may happen when it runs with a single argument as well, if it contains no shell meta-charactes.) Thus the characters that (would) have a special meaning in the shell may be used freely as literal characters in the command.

As for the second question -- if a command is formed with user-input it must always be checked *really* carefully! Note that one shouldn't literally use input in a command, but rather support keywords and parameters based on which the program composes the command. Avoiding the shell of course helps but any user input must be checked.

The injection bug is more of a programming error, whereby variable interpolation isn't used right and results in an unintended command; there is no need for malicious acts there, just for the "right" input that exposes the bug.

Answer (score 2):

All `capturex` does is save you from having to form a valid shell command. Some validation may still be needed.

---

> *What terminologies can be used to describe, how the code is executed with `capturex`?*

The source for the latest version of IPC::System::Simple is found [here](https://metacpan.org/release/IPC-System-Simple/source/lib/IPC/System/Simple.pm).

On non-Windows systems, `capturex` uses the `fork` and `execve` system calls via the [`open(my $pipe, '-|')`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and [`exec BLOCK LIST`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html) Perl functions respectively. This form of Perl's `exec` function executes the program directly rather than invoking a shell.

```
exec "ls foo";                                   # Executes /bin/sh
exec { "/bin/sh" } "/bin/sh", "-c", "ls foo";    # Equivalent to previous.
exec { "ls" } "ls", "foo";                       # Executes ls
```

---

> *Is it actually advisable to use this technique without input checking (I assume not) and if not, for what reason (attack vector)?*

What if you provide a relative path to the program to execute and the user set the `PATH` env var being used?

What if you provide a relative path to a file as an argument and the user set the current work directory?

What if you pass a string that starts with a `-`? That could be interpreted as an option rather than argument. (This is why you'd use `'ls', '--', $file` instead of `'ls', $file`.)

What if you pass `../../../../../../etc/passwd`? That could have undesired effect if the program uses the argument in a file path.

What if you pass a regex to a program, and the regular expression would take longer than the lifespan of the universe to fail to match?

It's possible that some validation still needs to occur. All `capturex` does is save you from having to form a valid shell command.

It might be the receiving program's job to do the validation, it might be yours, or it  might be a combination.

Comment: Thank you for your input. It helped me a lot. As a non-low-level-guy I'm particularly happy about your hint that the term "system call" seems to be adequate here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, check the values you send to external commands even if you don't think you are because you have some other security feature in place.

You have two different paths to executing external commands in your example:

1. Pass the shell a single string. In backticks, Perl constructs the entire command, and if it looks like the shell needs to handle it (globs, etc), the shell gets a chance to stick its fingers in. The shell then figures out what the command means, interprets its arguments, and does the work. So, the `*.tmp` is still a glob:

```
system $single_string;
exec $single_string;
```

2. Pass a list to the system and execute the command directly, with no shell in the way. `capturex` is doing this for you. There's no shell to interpret things such as `*.tmp`, so the arguments are their literal values. You'd see the same behavior with the list forms of `system` or `exec`:

```
system $program, @args;
exec $program, @args
```

You still have to be careful, because `@args` might be empty, so that looks like the single argument form again. There's a special form that handles that for you. It looks like you specify the program twice, but it all works out:

```
system { $program }, $program, @args;
exec { $program }, $program, @args
```

I discuss this in detail in [Mastering Perl](https://www.masteringperl.org)'s "Secure Programming Techniques" chapter, but you can read about some of it in [perlsec](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) too.

Comment: `system $program, @args` can invoke the shell on Windows even if `@args` isn't empty. I presume this was done to make shell builtins `md`, `copy`, `del`, etc appear to be utilities like their POSIX counterparts. (Same for exec.)

Comment: Thank you for your input and the mentioning of some traps with empty arrays!